# Javascript load order

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, javascript

I need to load some JS libraries the last of all. I used to achieve this using data-group param, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action> -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action> -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action> -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action> -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

and it was working fine, js files were loaded at the end.

Now i need to load some new libraries after these one, so i created a new data-group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_layered> <!-- find all category pages with layered navigation -->
        <update handle="mana_ajax" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.adapter.jquery.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/manapro_filterajax.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="category.products">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="m_ajax_update">
            <action method="setRenderedButNotSentBlocks"><blocks>m_ajax_update,head</blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfPageChanged"><updated_blocks>content,left,right,breadcrumbs,top.menu</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfParameterChanged"><updated_blocks>category.products,mana.catalog.leftnav,mana.catalog.rightnav</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setInterceptedLinkContainers"><css_selector>.mb-mana-catalog-leftnav,.mb-mana-catalog-rightnav,.block-layered-nav.m-topmenu,.block-layered-nav.m-top,.toolbar</css_selector></action>
            <action method="setExceptions"><regular_expr>[\?&amp;]options=|checkout/cart/add|catalog/product_compare/add|wishlist/index/add</regular_expr></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index> <!-- find all catalog search result page -->
        <update handle="mana_ajax" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.adapter.jquery.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/manapro_filterajax.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="search.result">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalogsearch.leftnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalogsearch.rightnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="m_ajax_update">
            <action method="setRenderedButNotSentBlocks"><blocks>m_ajax_update,head</blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfPageChanged"><updated_blocks>content,left,right,breadcrumbs,top.menu</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfParameterChanged"><updated_blocks>search.result,mana.catalogsearch.leftnav,mana.catalogsearch.rightnav</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setInterceptedLinkContainers"><css_selector>.mb-mana-catalogsearch-leftnav,.mb-mana-catalogsearch-rightnav,.block-layered-nav.m-topmenu,.block-layered-nav.m-top,.toolbar</css_selector></action>
            <action method="setExceptions"><regular_expr>[\?&amp;]options=|checkout/cart/add|catalog/product_compare/add|wishlist/index/add</regular_expr></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <cms_page_layered>
        <update handle="mana_ajax" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.adapter.jquery.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/manapro_filterajax.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="cms.products">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalog.rightnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="m_ajax_update">
            <action method="setRenderedButNotSentBlocks"><blocks>m_ajax_update,head</blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfPageChanged"><updated_blocks>content,left,right,breadcrumbs,top.menu</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfParameterChanged"><updated_blocks>content,mana.catalog.leftnav,mana.catalog.rightnav</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setInterceptedLinkContainers"><css_selector>.mb-mana-catalog-leftnav,.mb-mana-catalog-rightnav,.block-layered-nav.m-topmenu,.block-layered-nav.m-top,.toolbar</css_selector></action>
            <action method="setExceptions"><regular_expr>[\?&amp;]options=|checkout/cart/add|catalog/product_compare/add|wishlist/index/add</regular_expr></action>
        </reference>
    </cms_page_layered>
    <mana_optionpage_view>
        <update handle="mana_ajax" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.adapter.jquery.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/history.js</script><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/manapro_filterajax.js</name><params/><params><![CDATA[data-group="js003"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="option_view">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="setMClientSideBlock"><params><type>Mana/Core/Block</type></params></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="m_ajax_update">
            <action method="setRenderedButNotSentBlocks"><blocks>m_ajax_update,head</blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfPageChanged"><updated_blocks>content,left,right,breadcrumbs,top.menu</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setUpdatedBlocksIfParameterChanged"><updated_blocks>option_view,mana.catalog.leftnav,mana.catalog.rightnav</updated_blocks></action>
            <action method="setInterceptedLinkContainers"><css_selector>.mb-mana-catalog-leftnav,.mb-mana-catalog-rightnav,.block-layered-nav.m-topmenu,.block-layered-nav.m-top,.toolbar</css_selector></action>
            <action method="setExceptions"><regular_expr>[\?&amp;]options=|checkout/cart/add|catalog/product_compare/add|wishlist/index/add</regular_expr></action>
        </reference>
    </mana_optionpage_view>
</layout>
```

However, scripts tagged with js002 still loads after js003 ones.
How can i can change load order?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Antonio.